# Typescript compile warning but error occurred when I deploy vercel

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, eslint

I am updating existing website with react + typescript, webpack. I don't know well about webpack.

When I run npm start this warning occured "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any".
This website is working correctly but when I deploy it vercel, and complie error occurred
.
I don't know how can I fix it.
how can I fix this problem "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any"?

Below are eslintrc.json

```
{
  "extends": [
    "standard",
    "prettier",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "simple-import-sort"],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "error",
    "simple-import-sort/imports": "error"
  }
}
```